# Oracle Query - making columns values as column headers for multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have following table

```
Product Code Value time
ABC     ASK  15    31-AUG-18
ABC     BID  18    31-AUG-18
ABC     MID  15    31-AUG-18
ABC     ASK  11    31-AUG-18
ABC     BID  12    31-AUG-18
ABC     MID  10    31-AUG-18
ABC     ASK  1.3   31-AUG-18
ABC     BID  1.8   31-AUG-18
ABC     MID  1.5   31-AUG-18
```

and I want output as,

```
Product ASK BID MID Date
ABC     15  18  15  31-AUG-18
ABC     11  12  10  31-AUG-18
ABC     1.3 1.8 1.5 31-AUG-18
```

I tried this using pivot, but it is summing up all the values which is not the desired output. I am able to get something like this but this is not what is desired,

```
Product ASK   BID   MID   Date
ABC     27.3  31.8  26.5  31-AUG-18
```

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: What differentiates between the different rows with the same data? You need to be able to give your query something to differentiate between the various rows of product/code combinations. From what you have here, there doesn't appear to be any differences to key off of.

Comment: Hi Chris
data will be differentiated by the Date, I have given only one date in example, It will have dates for last 14 days from current date.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to give each code per group a unique identifier:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4088a/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Product, Code, Value, time ) AS
SELECT 'ABC', 'ASK', 15.0, DATE '2018-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'BID', 18.0, DATE '2018-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'MID', 15.0, DATE '2018-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'ASK', 11.0, DATE '2018-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'BID', 12.0, DATE '2018-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'MID', 10.0, DATE '2018-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'ASK',  1.3, DATE '2018-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'BID',  1.8, DATE '2018-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'MID',  1.5, DATE '2018-08-31' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Product,
       ask,
       bid,
       mid,
       time
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Product, Code, time ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT ( MAX( value ) FOR Code IN (
  'ASK' AS ask,
  'BID' AS bid,
  'MID' AS mid
) )
ORDER BY product, time, rn
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4088a/2/0)**:

```
| PRODUCT | ASK | BID | MID |                 TIME |
|---------|-----|-----|-----|----------------------|
|     ABC |  15 |  18 |  15 | 2018-08-31T00:00:00Z |
|     ABC |  11 |  12 |  10 | 2018-08-31T00:00:00Z |
|     ABC | 1.3 | 1.8 | 1.5 | 2018-08-31T00:00:00Z |
```

Ideally you should have another column to contain the ordering as using `ROWNUM` is not guaranteed to give the rows in a consistent order if Oracle reads the rows in a different order (or if row movement is enabled).

Comment: I was not able to understand the last part clearly , what would the ordering column contain ?